# Adjust position of newly created connecting point

Tags: microsoft-visio

I have added new connector on my shape and have connected arrow to it. I would like to change connector position in order to get straight connection line. It looks like I can move objects according to grid, but connector point doesn't. Hw to get stright connector line with changing connection point position?

[image]

Comment: Delete the arrow completely and make a new one to the existing point.

Comment: I will have the same curved arrow. Because other side is connected to other shape. How to get both connection points at the same level?

Comment: Usually you can anchor a point, join the other point and see how it looks.